# DateComponentsFormatter and .nanosecond

Tags: swift, time, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents, nsdatecomponentsformatter

So, I'm using a `DateComponentsFormatter` in a situation where I need to format only the nanoseconds of a given `TimeInterval`. The problem is that it just does not work as intended, or I'm confusing something here that I'm not aware of.

Here are 3 quick tests to illustrate what I'm saying.

### 1st Scenario

```
let fooFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()

fooFormatter.allowedUnits = [.second, .nanosecond]
fooFormatter.unitsStyle = .full
fooFormatter.collapsesLargestUnit = true
fooFormatter.allowsFractionalUnits = true

print(fooFormatter.string(from: 42.42424242424242424242424242424242))
```

**Output**: `Optional("42 seconds")`.

**Expected**: Because this collapses the "largest unit" - seconds in this case -, it's expected to be something like `(Optional("42.42424242424242424242424242424242 * 1e^9"))`.

### 2nd Scenario

```
let fooFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()

fooFormatter.allowedUnits = [.second, .nanosecond]
fooFormatter.unitsStyle = .full
fooFormatter.allowsFractionalUnits = true

print(fooFormatter.string(from: 42.42))
```

**Output**: `Optional("42 seconds")`.

**Expected**: Even without opting to not collapse the `.second`, I expected anything close to `(Optional("42 seconds 0.42 * 1e^9 nanoseconds"))`.

### 3rd Scenario

```
let fooFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
fooFormatter.allowedUnits = [.nanosecond]
fooFormatter.unitsStyle = .full
fooFormatter.allowsFractionalUnits = true

print(fooFormatter.string(from: 42.424242))
```

**Output**: `nil`.

**Expected**: Now it won't even recognize the `TimeInterval` as valid - when it's defined as the smallest fraction possible - and obviously expected everything in nanoseconds.

It's important to notice that I've used `allowsFractionalUnits = true`, which is even more **alarming**, because this behavior is also not working in the outputs given above (see the intended behavior [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponentsformatter/1413084-allowsfractionalunits)).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried of `fooFormatter.allowedUnits = [.calendar]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DateComponentsFormatter` does not support nanoseconds.

See the documentation for [`allowedUnits`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponentsformatter/1410216-allowedunits), which does not include nanoseconds. It says:

> The allowed calendar units are:
>
> - `year`
> - `month`
> - `weekOfMonth`
> - `day`
> - `hour`
> - `minute`
> - `second`
>
> Assigning any other calendar units to this property results in an exception.

Comment: So, allowing `.nanosecond` here is a bad design, right? I mean, why would you allow a typed `NSCalendar.Unit` where you can't exactly know how to deal with? There is no problem with backwards compatibility as well, because it just subclasses the `Formatter` class.
Also, because of this, the `.allowsFractionalUnits` does not work to separate into anything less than `second`, correct?
This API is not clear at all for me.

Comment: Yeah, there’s lots I’d quibble with: Why does it say it will raise an exception, but doesn’t? Why don’t they at least log some error message? Shouldn’t `allowsFractionalUnits` be a little more consistent and be married with something about `maximumFractionalDigits` or something like that? Like you, I once wasted more time than I’d like, trying to figure out what was going on here. That is an hour or two I wish I could get back. My new SOP is to double check both documentation and header comments before investing too much time diagnosing strange behavior.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense - and I'm in the same boat as you. Thanks for your time to answer me.

Comment: macOS 12.6.5 / Xcode 14.2: assigning `.nanoseconds` crashes. At least that is consistent now ...